# AndroidX ActionBar has disappeared: "Didn't find class "androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;" on path: DexPathList..."

Tags: android-actionbar, androidx

Working on a fitness tracking app for portfolio using AndroidX dependencies, ran into the following error:

"E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;" on path: DexPathList..." (Full error pasted below).

My actionbar won't appear, so neither will my menu options. In researching this problem, I see it might be a dependencies issue, so my dependencies in module:app are...

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

    // Room components
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.0.0'

    // Lifecycle components
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
}
```

And in project...

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


ext {
    roomVersion = '2.1.0-alpha06'
    archLifecycleVersion = '2.1.0-alpha04'
}
```

Thank you in advance! If any other code would be helpful, I'll be happy to provide.

```
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/zachg.gsctrainingandnutritiontracker-CH8ZaSUoVNBUoZhkK4ObiA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/zachg.gsctrainingandnutritiontracker-CH8ZaSUoVNBUoZhkK4ObiA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/zachg.gsctrainingandnutritiontracker-CH8ZaSUoVNBUoZhkK4ObiA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/zachg.gsctrainingandnutritiontracker-CH8ZaSUoVNBUoZhkK4ObiA==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/zachg.gsctrainingandnutritiontracker-CH8ZaSUoVNBUoZhkK4ObiA==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/zachg.gsctrainingandnutritiontracker-CH8ZaSUoVNBUoZhkK4ObiA==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/zachg.gsctrainingandnutritiontracker-CH8ZaSUoVNBUoZhkK4ObiA==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/zachg.gsctrainingandnutritiontracker-CH8ZaSUoVNBUoZhkK4ObiA==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/zachg.gsctrainingandnutritiontracker-CH8ZaSUoVNBUoZhkK4ObiA==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/zachg.gsctrainingandnutritiontracker-CH8ZaSUoVNBUoZhkK4ObiA==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/zachg.gsctrainingandnutritiontracker-CH8ZaSUoVNBUoZhkK4ObiA==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/zachg.gsctrainingandnutritiontracker-CH8ZaSUoVNBUoZhkK4ObiA==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/zachg.gsctrainingandnutritiontracker-CH8ZaSUoVNBUoZhkK4ObiA==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/zachg.gsctrainingandnutritiontracker-CH8ZaSUoVNBUoZhkK4ObiA==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:226)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:731)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:810)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1032)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2345)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5749)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/zachg.gsctrainingandnutritiontracker-CH8ZaSUoVNBUoZhkK4ObiA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:727)
                ... 12 more
```